# How to sort NSString like iTunes sorting?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I want to sort array of NSString using iTunes sorting rules. This rule ignores leading articles such as "a, an, The". There are some other rules. Apple has posted an article about it.
[iTunes 7.3: Changes in music sort order](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2642?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Anyone know any APIs in iOS 5.0 or later that can solve this?

Cheers,
Fedry

Comment: It looks like you will have to implement a custom sorting algorithm.

Comment: Once you get it working create a github project - fame and fortune await!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, iterate through the NSString's and check if the first words are words you don't want using `hasPrefix:`, then you can replace them with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`

Then you can sort the string's like this:

```
sortedArray = [stringArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Or you can just create your own method for comparing between 2 strings instead of using `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`

Comment: Or just use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` with a block, then you don't need to replace any strings or update the array.  The block can remove any unwanted prefixes and compare using temporary strings.